# Algorithm for solving systems of linear Diophantine inequalities

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, diophantine-equations

So, I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6639260/437603) on StackOverflow looking for a reasonably fast algorithm to solve systems of linear Diophantine inequalities and was pointed to [this article](http://www.kcam.biz/contents/downLoad.php?idx=752) by Cheng-Zhi Gao and Yu-Lin Dong. The problem is, they give the algorithm on pages 350-351, but part of step (3) appears to be missing.

My question for MathOverflow is, therefore, whether anyone knows either of another such algorithm or has an idea as to what the missing part of Gao and Dong's algorithm is.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: The question you linked to is on systems of linear + quadratic Diophantine equations, whereas this one restricts to linear Diophantine equations.

Comment: Please review: "Algorithms for solving systems of linear Diophantine inequalities," a previous MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37637… , whose title differs by just one character (pluralizing 'Algorithm').

Comment: @jc: Point taken!  

Comment: What's the complexity of their algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica implements an algorithm: see [the manual here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html):

---

[image: MathematicaDiophantine]

---

(**Added** in response to a comment query.)

The paper

> Hochbaum, Dorit S., and Anu Pathria. "Can a System of Linear Diophantine Equations be Solved in Strongly Polynomial Time?." (1994). ([PDF download link](http://riot.ieor.berkeley.edu/~dorit/pub/lde.pdf))

says that "no strongly polynomial algorithm exists for the problem of finding
the set of solutions to a system of linear diophantine equations
in the complexity model allowing the operations $\{ +, -, \times, /, \bmod, < \}$."
But if one assumes the *gcd* can be found quickly, then the system can 
be solved in strongly polynomial time.

Comment: Do you happen to know about the complexity of determining whether or not a system of inequalities has integer solutions?

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.  I appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 6):

[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) provides a function `NullspaceIntMat` which solves systems
of linear diophantine equations. The [documentation](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap25.html) says:

```
25.1-2 SolutionIntMat

* SolutionIntMat( mat, vec ) ───────────────────────────────────── operation

If  mat  is  a  matrix  with integral entries and vec a vector with integral
entries,  this  function  returns  a vector x with integer entries that is a
solution  of  the  equation x * mat = vec. It returns fail if no such vector
exists.

────────────────────────────────  Example  ─────────────────────────────────
  gap> mat:=[[1,2,7],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,19],[5,7,12]];;
  gap> SolutionMat(mat,[95,115,182]);
  [ 47/4, -17/2, 67/4, 0, 0 ]
  gap> SolutionIntMat(mat,[95,115,182]);
  [ 2285, -5854, 4888, -1299, 0 ]
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

The source code can be found in the file lib/matint.gi included in the GAP distribution.

There is also a function `SolutionNullspaceIntMat` which additionally
computes a basis of the integral nullspace of the given matrix.