# Local global principle for a system of polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis

Suppose $T$ be a system of polynomials homogenous of degree 2 solvable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$. So, can we claim that $T$ is solvable over $\mathbb{Q}$? I think as of now there is no local global principle proven for system of polynomials, but could there be one?

Comment: No. Look at [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle).

Comment: Please look at my updated question. In case of homogenous polynomials of degree 2 is the answer still no?

Comment: Restricting to homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$ (quadrics) doesn't help, because, as the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/11488/17064) explain, *every* projective variety can be written (after a suitable embedding) as an intersection of quadrics. So the answer to your question is no, there is no local-global principle. (But I don't think the question is stupid and  you shouldn't have been downvoted.)

Comment: In fact as soon as there are two equations of degree 2, the Hasse principle can fail. (With one, it's of course OK.) Given any elliptic curve E over Q whose Tate-Shafarevich group has 4-torsion, we can produce such a variety by taking a 4-torsion element, looking at the corresponding $E$-torsor, which fails the Hasse principle, and embedding it into $\mathbb P^3$ by a degree $4$ line bundle, where it will be the intersection of two quadrics.

Comment: Thanks. @WillSawin

Comment: Thanks @Gro-Tsen